# Swiper Slider Vertical Responsive

Tags: slider, swiper.js

My Question is about this example `https://codepen.io/fluxus/pen/rweVgp`

I would like 6 images to be displayed one below the other in the mobile display (full length). Instead of 2 images next to each other per slide.

Thanks and best regards,
Arno

So i think about to make a new slider section who is only showing at `@media screen and (max-width: 640px)`

Or does anyone have another solution for me?